# js doesn't execute 'else' statement

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an if-else statement in JavaScript which returns false, but doesn't execute the code inside 'else'.

part of the script inside the cshtml file:

```
if (@Session["mission"].ToString() != "1") {
    setInterval(function () { myTimer(ctxPoints, ctxLines); }, 1000 / @ViewBag.rate);  
} else {
    alert("hi");
}
```

In the debug the '@Session["mission"].ToString() != "1"' statement returns false, but nothing jumps to the screen.

Comment: What is `@Session["mission"].ToString()`? Did you mean `toString`?

Comment: please show the result of `@Session["mission"].ToString()`.

Comment: seems like Razor C# syntax so it is C# .ToString() with uppercase, but you should check the value of `@Session["mission"].ToString()` to make sure it is what you expect

Comment: you might need to do a null checking on `@Session["mission"]` before the `if else` statement, just to ensure that it is not null

Comment: It is not null.. the '@Session["mission"].ToString()' returns "2" (string type) and the '@Session["mission"].ToString() == "1"' returns false (bool type)

Comment: is the form do a postback before the script run? Suspect is the postback cause it bypass the script run

Comment: Any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: If `@Session["mission"].ToString()` returns `"2"`, why do you expect it to go the else clause?

Comment: your condition in the if statement is `!= "1"`, but in your test it is `== "1"`, so they are different

Comment: Thanks everyone, the problem was that Session["rate"] hasn't been initialized. That cause the problem even though we hadn't arrive to that part of code.

Answer (score 3):

You should open your web browser Developer console and see the real script which reaches the browser.

The Razor parts, `@Session["mission"].ToString()` doesn't exists in the browser script, because they are evaluated in the server, before sending them to the browser. So it makes no sense to try `@Session["mission"].ToString() != "1"` this in the console. In the browser you will get something like:
`if (1 != "1")`
or even like
`if ( != "1")`
which would provoke an error.

JavaScript does coalescing, so `1` is equal to `"1"` when you use the comparers `==` or `!=`, so you don't need to include the qoutes around the value (unless you get the error mentioned above: in this case, if you included the quotes, you'd get `if ("" != "1")`).

Coalescing is avoided by using the `!==` or `===` which would consider `1` not equal to `"1"`, so, including the quotes doesn't make any difference in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should clear Js code and c# code

```
if ("@Session["mission"].ToString()" != "1")
```

`Session["mission"].ToString()` this print string in c#, but you need to encapsulate it in quote to make this value get type `string`

Comment: hmm I can't see how that can be an issue even if it is `if (1 != "1")` instead of `if ("1" != "1")`, and I am guessing the quotes inside might need to be escaped

Comment: @slai you are right, my answer is only helping him has safer code. Problem must relate to another code problem

Comment: Downvoted beacuse the first comment is right. if you want to explain how to write "safer code" you should mention the difference between `!=` vs `!==` and `==` vs `===`

Comment: @JotaBe Yes, I upvoted for your answer because It is detail enough